# best way to save a python dictionary for use in java/android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, python-2.7, dictionary

Sorry, this might be a dumb question. I have a large dictionary in python that i hope to save to file and use the data in an android app. I have read on here i can save the dictionary using pickle, json or an sqlite database. I  have no experience with databases or json and while I'm willing to learn, I dont know which format is best for my purposes. I know android uses sqlite but can i easily load a db created in python in java? Or is using an sqlite database an overkill? thanks.

my dictionary is fairly simple:

```
data = {'category1':[list1, list2],'category2':[list4, list5]}
```

Comment: If the data is static, then JSON is probably a good choice.  I would say that sqlite would be useful if the data will be changed by the android app.

Comment: Yes, but for the transfer JSON is still the superior choice. Using a database to transfer data is not a good thing. You are transferring an interface where there really should just be data. The app still has the freedom to store that data in a database, and whenever it should pass it on to something else again, you encode it in JSON. XML, by the way, is as viable a choice as JSON is.

Comment: Agreed. If you are transferring the data in and out of your app regularly.  But if you are simply wanting to import an existing dictionary as a database into the app's resources, then transfers aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would go the JSON-route. You can serialize your Python Dictionary with [pickle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpickle) or [simple_json](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple_json), and there are quite a bunch of JSON-libraries for Java, too. (I used [this](http://json.org/java/) one, worked like a charm.)

The database seems to be a fairly bad choice for transporting data. The use case for a database is an entirely different one.